# Ephesians 2:3, "διανοιῶν" singular or plural?

Tags: word-study, ephesians

Ephesians 2:3 (GNT):

> 3. ἐν οἷς καὶ ἡμεῖς πάντες ἀνεστράφημέν ποτε ἐν ταῖς ἐπιθυμίαις τῆς σαρκὸς ἡμῶν, ποιοῦντες τὰ θελήματα τῆς σαρκὸς καὶ τῶν **διανοιῶν**, καὶ ἦμεν τέκνα φύσει ὀργῆς, ὡς καὶ οἱ λοιποί·

Ephesians 2:3 (Latin Vulgate):

> 3. in quibus et nos omnes aliquando conversati sumus in desideriis carnis nostrae facientes voluntates carnis et **cogitationum** et eramus natura filii irae sicut et ceteri

Ephesians 2:3 (DRB):

> In which also we all conversed in time past, in the desires of our flesh, fulfilling the will of the flesh and of our **thoughts**, and were by nature children of wrath, even as the rest:

English translations of the Greek word of this Verse (διανοιῶν), as Follow:

- thoughts (DRB).
- mind (KJV, ASV).
- minds (CEV, GNT, ABPE).

Is it singular or plural?, If it is plural, then, what is the most preferable: thoughts or minds?

What about the Latin word (cogitationum)?

Are there some Original Greek manuscripts having Plural, like what I introduced above, and some others Singular?, Hence, KJV and ASV?

Comment: It's plural.   If you lean the forms of the article (ie των) that is a big clue for unknown words.   I don't see any textual  variations for the NA28 on my iphone.   The various translations you provide are very interesting, but I have nothing on that.

Comment: It is a genitive feminine plural noun

Comment: @Dottard then why KJV, ASV translated it as Singular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

διανοιῶν (dianoiōn) is a genitive feminine plural noun from the root word, διάνοια (dianoia) which occurs 12 times in the NT and always in the singular except for Eph 2:3 where it is plural.

BDAG offers five meanings for this word but only three of them occur in the NT as follows:

#1 **the faculty of thinking, comprehending, and reasoning, *understanding, intelligence, mind***; eg, Eph 4:18, 1 John 5:20, Heb 8:10, 10:16.

#2 **mind as a mode of thinking, *disposition, thought, mind***; eg, 2 peter 3:1, Luke 1:51, Col 1:21.

#5 (only plural occurrence in NT) **mind in sensory aspect, *sense, impulse***, in a bad sense (Num 15:39), Eph 2:3.

Most modern versions render this words as:

- NIV: thoughts
- ESV: desires … of the mind
- BSB: thoughts
- NASB: desires … of the mind
- KJV: desires … of the mind

  … etc.  All these are allowable translations of διανοιῶν (dianoiōn) in the plural form.

Ellicott observes:

> In the lusts of our flesh, fulfilling the desires of the flesh and of
>   the mind.--The parallelism of these two clauses illustrates very
>   clearly the extended sense in which the word "flesh" is used by St.
>   Paul, as may indeed be seen by the catalogue of the works of the flesh
>   in Galatians 5:19-20. For here "the flesh," in the first clause,
>   includes both "the flesh and the mind" (or, more properly, the
>   thoughts) of the second; that is, it includes both the appetites and
>   the passions of our fleshly nature, and also the "thoughts" of the
>   mind itself, so far as it is devoted to this visible world of sense,
>   alienated from God, and therefore under the influence of the powers of
>   evil. In fact, in scriptural use the sins of "the flesh," "the world,"
>   and "the devil" are not different classes of sins, but different
>   aspects of sin, and any one of the three great enemies is made at
>   times to represent all.

Comment: +1, best answer, I hope you write something about the Latin word (cogitationum)?

Comment: I am sorry but I know very little about the Latin - I only know something about the Greek and Hebrew texts.